# How to count total number of rows when limit is added in android sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using SQLITE in android and I am having an issue I want to get the total count of row when limit is applied. For example if I apply limit of 100 for pagination but there are around 2000 data. I want to make a query where i can get only the 100 rows but the count should return 2000 i.e. total number of rows.
Things I have tried

```
SELECT * ,count(*) OVER() AS full_count FROM table LIMIT 0,100

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, * FROM table LIMIT 0,100
```

I know there are nested query which will work but I have around 2 million rows and for pagination, I am only fetching 100 rows at a time. So nested query would slow the process completely.

Comment: You really want in every row to see the total number of rows of the table?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to get the total number of rows:

```
with cte as(
  select count(*) total from table 
)
select *, (select total from cte) total
from table limit 0, 100
```

Comment: this works but still takes a lot of time. I think I will now make another db call only for getting the count

Comment: There is no other way than counting the total number of rows. *I will now make another db call...* This cte is is the 1 call that gets the total rows. It does not repeat for every row.